# Duplicate a character depending on its position in a string

Tags: javascript

I would like to duplicate every single letter in my string and uppercasing the first letter.

Like this case:
`accum("abcd") -> "A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd"`.

However, it alters the first letter of the string. I think I should add another iterator called "j". But I don't know how to do it.

Precisely, the only task remaining in my code is to move on to the next letter while saving the changes made for the first letter.

```
function accum(s) {
  var i = 0;
  while ( i<s.length){
    for (var j =i; j<i ; j++) {
    s=s[j].toUpperCase()+s[j].repeat(j)+"-";
    i+=1;
    
  }
    
  }
  return s.slice(0,s.length-1);
}
```

Comment: `[..."abcd"].map((c, n) => c.toUpperCase() + c.repeat(n)).join('-')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function accum(s) {
  let newString = '';
  for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    newString += s[i].toUpperCase() + s[i].repeat(i) + "-";
  }
  return newString.slice(0, newString.length - 1);
}
```

I guess you don't need two repetition loops at all (either you can keep the for or the while, i kept the for).

Your fundamental mistake was in this line: `s=s[j].toUpperCase()+s[j].repeat(j)+"-";` where you replaced `s` with the new string instead of concatenating it (`s +=` instead of `s =` ). Which would be wrong anyway because you are replacing the original string. You need another empty string to keep the changes separated from the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```js
function accum(s) {
   accumStr = '';
   for (var i=0; i < s.length; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
       accumStr += j !== 0 ? s[i] : s[i].toUpperCase();
     }
   }
   return accumStr;
}

console.log(accum('abcd')) //ABbCccDddd
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function accum(s) {
   let strArr = s.split('');
   let res = [];
   for (let i in strArr) {
      res.push(strArr[i].repeat(parseInt(i)+1));
      res[i] = res[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + res[i].slice(1);
   }

   return res.join('-');
}

console.log(accum('abcd'))
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use reduce method

```js
const accum = (str) => {
  return [...str].reduce(
    (acc, item, index, arr) =>
      acc +
      item.toUpperCase() +
      item.repeat(index) +
      (index < arr.length - 1 ? "-" : ""),
    ""
  );
};

console.log(accum("abcd")); //A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd
```